# Replace words in UITextView with custom view

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitextview

I'm dealing with a tricky situation related to an editable `UITextView`. When the user writes certain words on a `UITextView` I want to replace those words with a "tag" displaying an icon, the word (or words) and another icon.

just like this image:

[image]

I'm facing several problems here:

1. How to replace the target word with the view?
2. How to handle text deletion on the target word? If the text is, for example "football", the view will be displayed, but if I delete one character and get "footbal" the view should disappear and the text should come back.

Already made some tests with [DTRichTextEditor](https://github.com/Cocoanetics/DTRichTextEditor) and was able to detect the target words to highlight them changing their attributes, but this is way different.

Comment: I can make you textcolor change and with icon but tag I think I have to a bit try to it

Answer (score 0):

**NSTextAttachment** will allow you to insert an image into your UITextView (it works for any attributed string).

```
let attributedString = NSMutableAttributedString(string: "This is a string with an attached image: ")
let attachment = NSTextAttachment()        
attachment.image = UIImage(named: "imageToInsert")
let attachmentString = NSAttributedString(attachment: attachment)
attributedString.appendAttributedString(attachmentString)
textView.attributedText = attributedString
```

Of course to render your tag you will need to dynamically render your type to an image.  You can do this by making an attributed string for the tag text and calling **boundingRectWithSize** on it.  Using this size + the size of your other elements and your padding, you then get a graphics context and render your text, and your left icon and your right icon and call **UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext** to get the resulting image.

Answer (score 0):

You can look into [SubviewAttachingTextView](https://github.com/vlas-voloshin/SubviewAttachingTextView). It provides similar functionality.

To show a custom view:

```
let attachment = SubviewTextAttachment(view: CustomView(frame: frame))
textView.attributedText = NSAttributedString(attachment: attachment)
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow Cocavo. While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference. [Answers that are little more than a link may be deleted.](//stackoverflow.com/help/deleted-answers)